# Working of embedding layer in Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, tensorflow, python

Can someone please explain me the inputs and outputs along with the working of the layer mentioned below

```
model.add(Embedding(total_words, 64, input_length=max_sequence_len-1))
```

> total_words = 263
>
> max_sequence_len=11

Is 64, the number of dimensions?

And why is the output of this layer (None, 10, 64)

Shouldn't it be a 64 dimension vector for each word, i.e (None, 263, 64)

Comment: Hi. This seems to be a programming problem. Right? In that case, it's off-topic here, and you should ask it on Stack Overflow. Please, read https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all the information about the Embedding Layer of Tensorflow [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding).

The first two parameters are `input_dimension` and `output_dimension`.

- The input dimensions basically represents the vocabulary size of your model. You can find this out by using the `word_index` function of the `Tokenizer()` function.
- The output dimensions are going to be Dimensions of the input of the next `Dense Layer`

The output of the Embedding layer is of the form `(batch_size, input_length, output_dim)`. But since you specified the input_length parameter, your layers input will be of the form `(batch, input_length)`. That's why the output is of the form (None, 10 ,64).

Hope that clears up your doubt ☺️

Comment: Not particularly helpful for understanding embedding layers - the documentation is unhelpful. How What transformation does the embedding layer perform on the input? Why does specifying an input length result in dropping the `output_dim`? What is the` output_dim` in the first place? How does an embedding layer differ from simply performing these steps in data preprocessing, and can you give some concrete examples?

Answer (score 0):

In the `Embedding` layer the first argument represents the input dimensions (which is typically of considerable dimensionality). The second argument represents the output dimensions, a.k.a the dimensionality of the reduced vector. The third argument is for the sequence length. In essence, an Embedding layer is simply learning a lookup table of shape `(input dim, output dim)`. The weights of this layer reflect that shape. The output of the layer, however, will of course be of shape `(output dim, seq length)`; one dimensionality-reduced embedding vector for each element in the input sequence. The shape you were expecting is actually the shape of the weights of an embedding layer.